Beta distribution loss function
I'm trying to build a model to predict the ratio of two numbers. The distribution of this ratio takes the form of a beta distribution, between 0 and 1. So far, I've been using different existing loss functions in XGBoost, without success. The only ideas I have for getting around this are:

Creating my own loss function that can model a beta distribution. However I wouldn't know how to implement this- do I need to reparametrize the negative log likelihood of the beta distribution in terms of the mean?
I don't necessarily have to use XGBoost. I'm open to trying other packages that could better approach this problem (GLMs, etc.).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance


What do you mean by "without success"? 2. What do you mean by "the distribution takes the form of a beta"? Are you predicting a full predictive density of these ratios?



What do you mean by "loss function that can model a beta distribution"?



By without success I mean that the models I've built aren't very good. I'm assuming they're not very good because the loss functions I'm using have assumptions about the distribution - a Normal, Gamma, Tweedie. Xgboost can handle these, but there's nothing built-in for the beta distribution. I'm hoping that with the right loss function, the shape of the predictions will more closely match the shape of the actuals, that of a beta distribution with a long left  tail.


OK. I believe we will need to unpack a few things here. Most loss functions make very few assumptions about the conditional (!) distribution of what you are modeling. What is much more important is what you are aiming for: point predictions or predictive densities. Which one is it?

(As an aside, it is absolutely fine if your predictions vary less than the observations, and may well have a completely different shape, see here.)

I'm trying to predict the ratios outright, so point predictions. When i do this using any of the loss functions in xgboost, I get an r squared of typically around 0.3. So I assumed it was because I'm modelling an unconventional distribution - Most values are between 0.8 and 0.95 with a long left tail, something quite hard to predict.

What is the exact problem here? It seems to be about 'how to create a custom loss function for xgboost'. But where do you get stuck? Do you need help about programming such custom function, or do you need help about defining such function? Why not just use the log-likelihood as loss function?

You haven't responded to "the distribution takes the form of a beta". How is it that it does take that form. Do you have theoretical reasons for that?

This ratio of these numbers, is it like $\frac{X}{X+Y}$? Can't you predict these $X$ and $Y$ more directly?

Why is the ratio bounded above by 1?

You should first decide which functional of the conditional (unknown, likely not even specified, but always lurking in the background) distribution of your outcome you want to predict. Then, and only then can you decide which loss function to use, because different loss functions elicit different functionals. If you want the conditional expectation, use the MSE or a variant thereof. If you want the conditional median, use the MAE. See Kolassa (2020, IJF).
For the preceding paragraph, it does not matter what this conditional distribution is. (Except that of course you can't meaningfully elicit a functional that does not exist, like the expectation of a Cauchy distribution.)
Of course, the conditional distribution does matter for how good your prediction can be. So what you need to be aiming for is to reduce the conditional remaining uncertainty. This can very often only be done by investing domain knowledge and modeling with features: How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?.
If your $R^2$ is "only" 0.3, that may simply be the way things are. In many fields, such an $R^2$ would be almost impossible to achieve. In other fields, such an $R^2$ would get you laughed out of the seminar room. It absolutely depends on the signal to noise ratio. Which is just a different way of expressing the previous paragraph.

Thanks for the concise answer. I'll have a proper think through your points. Just a question - what's happening in XGBoost or other packages when you specify a loss function to be Gamma, Poisson, or Tweedie? I had always imagined it to be because the distribution of actuals has that shape, and so picking the right loss function will "force" your predictions into the right distribution (don't quite have the terminology to explain what I'm trying to say, but in effect that you need a loss function that matches your distribution specifically). In those cases it seems to go beyond the mean/median

That is an excellent question... which I don't have an answer to. I don't know what "a Gamma loss function" would be. A loss function is a mapping that takes a prediction (whether point or density) and an actual and maps to a number. I don't see where a distribution comes in. Sorry, and good luck!

Beta-regression exists, and it is solved in terms of the Beta negative log-likelihood. See beta-regression. The Beta distribution, as you might well know, has two parameters (which can be stated as location and scale/precision, or otherwise alpha and beta). The problem is that, unlike the Gaussian, these parameters will not be "decoupled", you have to estimate both jointly.
One problem I see is your statement: "The distribution of this ratio takes the form of a beta distribution, between 0 and 1". If this is taken to imply the marginal distribution of the ratio is Beta-distributed, then the consideration of Beta regression is out of the window. Regression is about conditional distributions, i.e., given your input variables $X$, the outcome is distributed like $p(Y|X) = \text{B}(\alpha(X), \beta(X)).$
See:

Regression for an outcome (ratio or fraction) between 0 and 1
Why Beta/Dirichlet Regression are not considered Generalized Linear Models? (disclaimer: my own question)


On the one hand, you are of course completely correct. On the other hand, OP is explicitly not modeling the (beta or other) predictive density, but looking for a point prediction. They are not saying which one number summary they want, which is what I go into in my answer. They may want the conditional expectation. Or a conditional median. Or a conditional quantile. All of which can of course be extracted from a predictive beta distribution. I am just a little skeptical whether a full beta regression is not likely to confuse them even more...
